# How to work with POSIXlt in R

Tags: r, date, time, posixlt

I am trying to do some analysis with a csv file that I have loaded into R. I was doing the following to access specific values via test[[3]][[1]] for example to get the specific value:

```
test <- read.csv(file = "test.csv")
test <- data.frame(lapply(test, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Otherwise I would have gotten something like this:

```
> chicago[[3]][[1]]
[1] 08/02/2002 11:00:00 AM
19747 Levels: 01/01/2001 03:49:00 AM 01/01/2001 06:17:00 PM 01/01/2001 12:00:00 AM ... 12/31/2015 11:46:00 AM
```

Since one column is saving dates I was converting it to POSIXlt.

```
test[[3]] <- strptime(test[[3]], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

The values are now being changed as expected, for example:

```
01/28/2004 06:30:00 PM -> 2004-01-28 18:30:00
```

Trying to access the values now, I realised though that for example test[[3]][[1]] doesn't give the specific date - instead I get a list that contains every second of each row.

Testing a bit around, I found out that the POSIXit type is a bit "different"; meaning the value mentioned above seems to be some kind of list, being like this:

```
> unlist(unclass(value))
   sec    min   hour   mday    mon   year   wday   yday  isdst   zone gmtoff 
   "0"    "0"   "11"    "2"    "7"  "102"    "5"  "213"    "1" "CEST"     NA
```

So my question is: is there a way to get values like "2004-01-28 18:30:00" instead of a list about the whole column?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `POSIXlt` instead of `POSIXct` (which I do prefer for date-times)?

Answer (score 3):

You are making your life too difficult.  You can parse to either Date or Datetime *for an entire column*.  No need for `lapply`.

You (in general) do not want `POSIXlt` representation.  Look into existing package such as my (relatively recent) [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) package (also [on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime)) which even converts from `factor` for you -- and does not require explicit format strings, origin values or other holdups.

But as your post does not contain a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I cannot help with more concrete steps.